# How can I change defaultValue of input when I have got props from the server in admin-on-rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm working with [admin-on-rest](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/) and I'm creating `<Edit>` component. In `<Edit>` I have `<RadioButtonInputGroup>` with defined defaultValue:

```
const defaultValues = {
  user_to_app_to_role_by_user_id: 5
};
...

const roleChoices = [
  { id: 5, name: 'User' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Admin' }
];
...

<Edit title="Edit user">
          <SimpleForm defaultValue={defaultValues}>
            <RadioButtonGroupInput
              label="Role"
              source="user_to_app_to_role_by_user_id"
              choices={roleChoices}
            />
            ...
```

But now I want to et up default value like value that I want to get from this.props, like this:

```
const defaultValues = {
  user_to_app_to_role_by_user_id: this.getRoleByProps()
};
...
getRoleByProps() {
  let role;
  if(this.props.user && this.props.user.roles) {
    return this.props.user.roles[0].role_id
  }
  else {
   return 5;
  }
}
```

In process of debugging I see, that when properties come in, my defaultValues object update. But what's problem is that component `<RadioButtonGroupInput>` doesn't update. It's value as before. 
I already tried to inpur default velues in state and write `<SimpleForm defaultValue={this.state.defaultValues}` but it doesn't help. 
Maybe you can give some advice for me what I can do in thi situation.

Comment: You are missing a closing paranthesis for the if statement,

Comment: thanks, I changed it.